# How to specify transitive package dependency during package upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

While upgrading packages using `ncu` in my nodejs project which uses `npm`, is it possible to specify to upgrade all packages other than React 17 and all other packages that depend on React 17. So, basically being able to specify a transitive dependency on a specific Package version to be excluded from upgrade

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use ncu (npm-check-updates) to exclude a specific package and its dependencies from being upgraded.

You can use the --reject flag followed by a regular expression to match the package name you want to exclude. For example, to exclude React 17 and any package that depends on it, you can run the following command

ncu -a --reject "^react@17"

This command will upgrade all packages except those that match the regular expression ^react@17, which will exclude React 17 and any package that depends on it.

Note that the ^ character in the regular expression matches the beginning of the package name, and the @17 specifies that the version of React that should be excluded is 17. You can adjust the regular expression to match the specific package and version that you want to exclude.